# Read Dates as Strings with Spreadsheet Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

I have been looking for a way to read out an Excel spreadsheet with keeping the dates that are in them being kept as a string. Unfortunately I can't see if this is possible or not, has anyone managed to do this or know how?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the Row class of the spreadsheet gem:

http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/Spreadsheet/Row.html

There's a lot that you can get there, but the Row#formatted method is probably what you want:

```
row = sheet.to_a[row_index] # Get row object
value = row.formatted[column_index]
```

The formatted method takes all the Excel formatting data for you and gives you an array of Ruby-classed objects

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `row.at(col_index)` method..
You can refer to [this page](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html)